# AMQP client message format

Tags: architecture, protocols, amqp

From what I understand of AMQP, "clients" of the message bus can use any format they wish i.e. the fabric is opaque to the client messages.

Is it a common practice to include an overhead specifying the protocol format of the messages for a given "exchange"?  e.g. have a "\n" terminated first line specifying the protocol MIME-type (XML, JSON etc.)

Or is there a configuration option I haven't stumbled upon yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the *content-type* can be specified hence no need to encapsulate this overhead manually.